# Typedef enum-like variable but with arbitrary increments

Tags: c

I'm interested in doing something like an `enum` but where the increments aren't always one, sort of like this:

```
typedef enum{this=0,that=3,something=5}example;
```

I am wondering what is the best way to do something like this, as I gather the above is either not possible or not advised. Basically I want to use `kConstantNames` that refer to specific integer values... should i just use a `#define` statement instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's allowable, quite normal, and definitely better than `#define`.

Minor nit-pick: `#define` isn't a statement. It's a preprocessor construct that is expanded out before the compiler proper even sees it.

Comment: i thought "enum" referred to an enumerated set of values with increments of 1 between?

Comment: That's the default. Assigning specific values, as you have done, is legal, and is commonly used to define bit-masks (among other things): `enum { foo = 1, bar = 2, baz = 4, woz = 8, ... }`.

Comment: do they need to be in sequential order? or could you put baz=4 before foo=1?

Comment: No, they can be in any order you want. The only rule is that any item without an explicit value gets the value of its predecessor plus one (zero if it's the first item).

Comment: You just need to be careful when mixing implicit and explicit enumeration constants: `enum { foo = 1, bar, baz = 2, ... }` will result in `bar` and `baz` with the same value of 2.